# How to upload image to target folder on tinyMCE using justboil plugin?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce, justboil.me

I am using justboil image upload plugin on tinyMCE. I am able to upload image but that image instead of being uploaded to target folder “media” is uploaded to htdocs folder (xampp), means it does not even get uploaded to my root folder tutorials

```
$config['img_path'] = `C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\media`;
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path'];
```

where my code is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the upload folder explicitly (https://github.com/vikdiesel/justboil.me/blob/master/config.php):

```
$config['img_path'] = '/images/somefolder'; // Relative to domain name
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work on xampp, gives error **The upload path does not appear to be valid. **

Comment: you need to choose an own existing folder! instead of  '/images/somefolder' (that is just an example)

Comment: :) yup I know that '/media'; in my case but still that error

Comment: you know that you cannot concatenate $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; - you have to define that directory relative to your domain name